# Why can I not access Props using React Functional Component v17?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, onsubmit

Why can't I access props? Also, when i try to submit, the console says that props.OnSubmit is not a function. Am I not supposed to use props in this newer version of React and must use another hook?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const TodoForm = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  console.log("props:", props);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit({
      id: uuidv4(),
      text: input,
    });
  };

 return (
   <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Add todo"
       value={input}
       name="text"
       onChange={handleChange}
       className="todo-input"
     />
     <button className="todo-btn"> Add todo</button>
   </form>
 );
};

export default TodoForm;
```

Comment: That _is_ how you access props, you should look at where you're _using_ `TodoForm`.

Comment: How are you implementing the component? Are you using the prop onSubmit? <TodoForm onSubmit={...} />. Also maybe name it onFormSubmit.